# How can I backup all my software in files to reinstall on another Linux system?

Tags: package-management, backup

Is there a way to backup all my programs, software, maybe even libraries and their data on a Linux system like it is for apps and their data on rooted Android with TitaniumBackup?
I'd like to backup all my current programs in files and activate them on another Linux system again.

Comment: I would recommend installing them on the new machine normally.  It might seem lengthy but what you are trying is likely to be a hazardous path that turns out longer.

Comment: For what distribution? Package management is very distribution-dependent. Also, unlike Android which prevents applications from interacting and considers data to belong to applications, Linux considers data to belong to users and puts all of a user's data in the same place, namely their home directory.

Comment: It's for Ubuntu and related systems, if working, e. g. Xubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backing up system files on UNIX type systems is generally not done on a file by file basis.

If you are trying to migrate a system to new hardware, just boot the old machine with a live image such as knoppix and use `dd` to image your hard drive partitions to a remote machine over the network or to an external hard drive. Then you can boot the live image on the new machine and use `dd` to write the disk images to the new partitions. Note that the new machine will have the same configuration as the old machine, so if you are trying to "clone" a system while leaving the old system up then you will need to change a few configuration settings such as the hostname and any static IP addresses. Depending on what software you are using there may be other small changes that you need to make if both of the systems are to be used concurrently.

If fully cloning a system is not what you are after, and the new system is the same Linux distribution as the old system, then use the package manager to get a list of installed software. That list can then be used by the package manager on the new system to install all of the software and libraries. After that just copy the data and configuration files from the old machine to the new one. [Here is a URL describing this process for various distributions.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-get-list-installed-software-reinstallation-restore.html)

Any software that was installed without using the package manager will need to be copied manually. In which case `scp` or `rsync` are the tools you are looking for. Such software is usually installed in `/opt` (for older "legacy" software) or under `/usr/local/`. You could clone the whole system this way, but if you miss anything important you will run into issues (hence why the previous two methods I mentioned are preferred). On Debian based distributions all of the important files should be contained in the following folders: `/bin`, `/etc`, `/home`, `/lib`, `/lib64`, `/lib32`, `/opt` (if it isn't empty), `/root`, `/srv`, `/sbin`, `/usr`, and `/var`. It is also a good idea to boot from a live image to do this as well since it will ensure that none of the files are being modified (especially in `/var/log`) while you are trying to copy them. This would look something like:

```
rsync --progress -a -r /bin /etc /home /lib /lib64 /lib32 /opt /root /srv /sbin /usr /var username@remotehostname.domainname:/
```

Comment: The Link you suggested about doing a backup via the package manager is quite what I was looking for, thx!

Comment: I am glad it was helpful.